# H2 - General error: "The write format 3 is larger than the supported format 2 [2.1.212/5]" [50000-212] HY000/50000 (Help)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, intellij-idea, h2

I'm trying connect to h2 console to use it with hibernate
but get this error:
General error: "The write format 3 is larger than the supported format 2 [2.1.212/5]" [50000-212] HY000/50000 (Help)

Here is the link to my h2 console:
http://localhost:8084/personsApp/h2-console/login.do

all questions I found about write format was "The write format XX is smaller..."
is someone has any idea?
[image]

Comment: Do you get this error in IntelliJ IDEA? If so, please provide a screenshot of the H2 Data Source settings -> 'General' tab.

Comment: No this error arrive in console link http://localhost:8084/personsApp/h2-console/login.do

Answer (score 3):

You need to upgrade your version of H2 to 2.2.220. H2 2.1.212 cannot read database files created by H2 2.2.*.